# How to make Workbook.Worksheet variable dynamic?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate the task creation in our project management software.

Currently, I get three separate excel files from our customer (that change from project to project) take the data from specific columns, format them into a single cell in an import template provided by the pm software company.

This is the first VBA project I've ever tried and I've got technically working along with some formulas added inside the template workbook. But I would like to be able to make the process of changing the workbook.worksheet location easier than opening the macro editor, opening each individual file, copy & paste the workbook/worksheet name into the macro.

Is there a way to create a userform to browse the filepath and get the workbook.worksheet info?

```
Sub TaskCreation()
Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim vssCopy As Worksheet
Dim acsCopy As Worksheet
Dim idsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim ImportDest As Worksheet
Dim vssCopyLastRow As Long
Dim acsCopyLastRow As Long
Dim idsCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set vssCopy = Workbooks("Example1").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set acsCopy = Workbooks("Example2").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set idsCopy = Workbooks("Example3").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
  1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  vssCopyLastRow = vssCopy.Cells(vssCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  acsCopyLastRow = vssCopy.Cells(vssCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  idsCopyLastRow = vssCopy.Cells(vssCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
  2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  3. Copy & Paste Data
  vssCopy.Range("A2:A" & vssCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
  vssCopy.Range("E2:E" & vssCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)
  vssCopy.Range("L2:L" & vssCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow)
    
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  acsCopy.Range("A2:A" & acsCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
  acsCopy.Range("B2:B" & acsCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)
    
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
  idsCopy.Range("A2:A" & idsCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
  idsCopy.Range("B2:B" & idsCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow)
  idsCopy.Range("E2:E" & idsCopyLastRow).Copy _
    wsDest.Range("C" & lDestLastRow)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for [Application.GetOpenFilename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename).

Comment: FYI your "Find last used row" uses the same worksheet `vssCopy` 3 times?  If you meant to do that, you only need one "last row" variable.

Comment: "Is there a way to create a userform to browse the filepath and get the workbook.worksheet info?" of course you can. You can create a UserForm, which has a list box or combo box, and then reads the Excel file under a specified directory, and store its path and other information inside the data related to each list item. Use thiese info for where the code need, like the argument in "Workbooks()".